# Image flickering when moving a piece in chess game #c .visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, chess

I've been searching regarding to this problem but i can't make it work :( 
here's my code :

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace Chess.Source
{
    public sealed class GraphicsBuffer
    {
        private Graphics graphics;
        private int height;
        private Bitmap memoryBitmap;
        private int width;

        public Graphics Graphics
        {
            get { return graphics; }
        }

        public void CreateGraphicsBuffer(Graphics g, int W, int H)
        {
            if (memoryBitmap != null)
            {
                memoryBitmap.Dispose();
                memoryBitmap = null;
            }

            if (graphics != null)
            {
                graphics.Dispose();
                graphics = null;
            }

            if (W == 0 || H == 0)
                return;


            if ((W != width) || (H != height))
            {
                width = W;
                height = H;

                memoryBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
                graphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryBitmap);
            }
        }

        public void Render(Graphics g)
        {
            if (memoryBitmap != null)
            {
                g.DrawImage(memoryBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0, width, height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Answer (score 0):

The flickering is most likely due to the fact that you're not using [double buffering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b367a457(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can enable double buffering on the forms element you're drawing to by setting it's `DoubleBuffering` property to `true`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: where can i put that code sir?

Comment: Wherever you set properties on controls in your code, most likely the constructor.

Comment: i have done the doublebuffering property to true but the thing is my image is not missing and will only appear when i press on the board

Comment: When are you calling the `Render()` method? It seems like you're relying on your window to deal with repaints when you should be actively calling the render method instead. You need to read more deeply into the .NET graphics documentation.